# How to push new items to an array inside of an object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

My JSON currently looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 393,
    "item" : 34,
    "comments" : [
        {
            "name" : "kevin",
            "messages" : [
                "item",
                "item"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "ryan",
            "messages" : [
                "item",
                "item"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I push new items onto the messages array for the first or second item in the comments array?

```
db.newcon.update({_id: 393}, { $push: { comments['kevin']: {messages: 39 }   }  })
```

Comment: there is no `kevin` key in your structure. you'd have to FIND which of the comment array entries contains kevin, then push into that.

Comment: you want to add `39` in `messages` where `comments.name : kevin` right?

Comment: That is correct @yogesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and `$` operator you can update your documents check below query :

```
db.collectionName.update({"_id":393,"comments":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"kevin"}}},
                         {"$push":{"comments.$.messages":39}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
var newMessage = '39';
comments.forEach(function(item) {
   if (item.name === 'kevin') {
        item.comments.push(newMessage);
   }
});
```

Comment: hi this also possible using mongo query not required to `forEach` on every documents. Here, OP not explain what expected output required.

Comment: It is one option, since javascript is one of the tags, I did not know that mongodb could have arrays, since I have not worked with mongodb.